# Transmute string to list of dictionaries with double quotes

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I am working on python code to convert object to list of dictionaries in double quotes.
Below are the steps:

Script calls api endpoint returns below output.

```
    output:[{value:10,mode:"low",unit:"kg"},
            {value:5,mode:"intermediate",unit:"kg"},
            {value:10,mode:"expert",unit:"kg"},
            {value:2,mode:"admin",unit:"kg"}]
```

My goal is to convert this data to list of dictionary objects.

I tried to convert above output to json format using `json.loads` :

> json.loads(re.sub(r'(\w+?):', r'"\1":', output))

but double quotes are getting replaced with single quotes.

I tried

> json.dumps(re.sub(r'(\w+?):', r'"\1":', output))

but this returned below string instead of list of dictionaries.

```
    [{"value":10,"mode":"low","unit":"kg"},
     {"value":5,"mode":"intermediate","unit":"kg"},
     {"value":10,"mode":"expert",unit:"kg"},
     {"value":2,"mode":"admin","unit":"kg"}]
```

My questions:

1. Is there is a way to convert above string to list of dictionaries in double quotes?
2. Can I add new dictionary object `{"value":5,"mode":"admin","unit":"kg"}` to above list in double quotes?

Please help.

Comment: this is a string `output:[{value:10,mode:"low",unit:"kg"},{value:5,mode:"intermediate",unit:"kg"},{value:10,mode:"expert",unit:"kg"},{value:2,mode:"admin",unit:"kg"}]` ?

Comment: Yes this is string

Answer (score 0):

The type of quotes you're using isn't stored in the dictionary. You can (though shouldn't for style reasons) mix double and single quotes as much as you want, as long as each individual string is wrapped in the same type of quotes on either side. CPython outputs dictionaries using single quotes but that's an implementation detail and doesn't mean anything. When converting to a JSON string, double quotes will be written as that is what the JSON spec requires.